# Magento import invalid value for type ""

Tags: magento

Im trying to import a simple CSV file with only one row:

```
sku,store,attribute_set,category_ids,status,visibility,tax_class_id,weight,price,name,description,short_description

PCR CLOTH,Standard,simple,0,1,1,1,0,19,"Clothing strip original","asdasdasdsd","sss sssssss"
```

And i receive this:

Skip import row, is not valid value “” for field “type”

Comment: There are a multitude of ways to import something in Magento.  People won't know how to help you unless they know how you're importing something.  If you can't describe how you're importing something, you're better off finding a different forum.

Comment: Is "type" a required column? If so then why is it missing?

Comment: I started getting these errors after truncating the mage_dataflow_batch_export and mage_dataflow_batch_import tables, per a helpful article on the internet (it also suggested deleting several log-related tables, to speed up Magento).  I can't see anything wrong with these files, and in fact the same ones that were working before now do not.  I am going to have to restore from an old back unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

You need a column for "type".  Usually the value for that row will be "simple".

On another note, I would recommend switching to XML import and export formats.  Then export your catalog and use that as a template for future imports.  The XML format works better with special characters and the export will have all the fields that you will need for an import (plus the optional ones).

Comment: in terms of layman importing products into Magento, i dont think XML is the most viable way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You should use appropriate csv format for import.
Lines must be separated by **tabs**, make sure that you are using right **value delimiter** ("," for example), and also make sure that **values are enclosed** in double quotes.

If you want to see valid sample, you can do export of all products, and take a look at resulting file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround some of those first items in quotes so its interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error because I did have any items in the category I had entered. The category was in the system, but no products were there.

I was able to fix it by assigning them all to a category that had products in the CSV, and then after the import, moving to the category I did want them in.

May be a possibility..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly set your file format ansi or utf-8. Then you will get rid off of proble.
use editplus then goto
Document-file encoding then set it ansi and save the file.
then try import again.